# Get the force and direction of a throwned object in VR Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get the Force Value and the Vector3 direction of an object thrown in VR?


I know i can grab and throw an object with XR Grab Interactable.

But for some reason, I require the TrackPosition and TrackRotation to be turn off.

Just like in this picture;

[image]

And therefore Is there any possibility to acquire the Force Value and the direction of the object when the Player thrown it? 

Thank you in advance for any insight...^^,

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Rigidbody attached, you can read the Rigidbody.velocity

Comment: yes..  but the rigidbody itself is not giving any velocity when "thrown" . :)